# How to remove strings from list permanently?

Tags: python, string, list

```
fileList = ['a.txt', 'b.pdf','c.exe','d.pdf','e.mp3']
extension = '.pdf'

for i in fileList:
    if extension in i:
        print i
>>>
b.pdf
d.pdf
>>>
```

The script prints out the list I want...
BUT how do I get the script to alter the `fileList` to read:

`fileList = ['b.pdf', 'd.pdf']`???

I tried...

```
for i in fileList:
    if extension not in i:
```

followed by...

```
del i, fileList.pop, fileList.remove, etc
```

BUT `fileList` never permanently changes.

Answer (score 3):

Certain list operations are not very efficient. `insert` and `remove` from random locations are a couple that are O(n).

Removing items from the list you are iterating with a `for` loop is also a good way to introduce bugs as items immediately following the removed ones will be skipped.

It turns out it is usually much more efficient to create a new list filtering out the undesired items

```
file_list = ['a.txt', 'b.pdf','c.exe','d.pdf','e.mp3']
extension = '.pdf'

new_list = [x for x in file_list if x.endswith(extension)]
```

Notice that I changed the logic to use `endswith` to prevent inadvertent matches in the filename path

Answer (score 1):

You should try iterating over the copy of `fileList` And removing from `fileList` . Example -

```
>>> fileList = ['a.txt', 'b.pdf','c.exe','d.pdf','e.mp3']
>>> extension = '.pdf'
>>>
>>> for i in fileList[:]:
...     if not i.endswith(extension):
...             fileList.remove(i)
...
>>> fileList
['b.pdf', 'd.pdf']
```

But you do not actually need this, you can use simple list comprehension, to just make the name `fileList` point to the one where the files without the extension do not exist. Alos, you can use `string.endswith` to check if a string ends with a value.

Example -

```
>>> fileList = ['a.txt', 'b.pdf','c.exe','d.pdf','e.mp3']
>>> extension = '.pdf'
>>> fileList = [i for i in fileList if i.endswith(extension)]
>>> fileList
['b.pdf', 'd.pdf']
```

Comment: It will fail in cases where the name is name.pdf.jpg

Comment: Thanks , changed it to use `endswith` .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
del list[index]
#example :-
del list[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the built-in function [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter), this way:

```
fileList = filter(lambda s:s.endswith(extension), fileList)
```

Comment: List comprehension is generally faster than `filter`. Also `filter` doesn't return a list in Python3. There really isn't an upside, so it's not been commonly used since Python1

Comment: @JohnLaRooy..thanks for the feedback... :)...is it the same for `itertools` module, which has `ifilter()`?

Comment: `filter` in Python3 behaves like `ifilter` in itertools. It's easier to use list comprehensions and generator expressions as they won't need porting moving between Python2 and Python3